# Deploy angular app universal to azure service

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, server-side-rendering

I have my angular app with all angular universal config flow.
As I understand I need get after build pipeline `server` folder. I have it

[image]

When I use my app without ssr I set the path in Azure App Settings to my `browser` folder with `web.config`

[image]

And app work good.

When I set the folder `server` instead `browser` I have the mistake in web browser

[image]

As I know I have this mistake because I don't have `web.config` file in my `server` folder.

I try to add it but after build it disapeare. How I can fix it? Mya be the problem not in web.config file?

Comment: Can you share your Code Repo ?

Comment: Make sure the default document is added in Configuration section.

Comment: In `Path mappings` add the `Physical Path` as  `site\wwwroot\YourWebApName` and check once.

Comment: You could try this [`web.config`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/add-dotnet-ssr/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/web.config) with the `Rewrite` section uncommented. It doesn't work on my live environment, but it does work on Local IIS

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76805708/angular-universal-passenger-error-on-plesk-server?noredirect=1#comment135445176_76805708) a comment from someone who claims it works...

Answer (score 1):

Check the below steps to Deploy angular app universal to azure app service.

I have followed the [Angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/universal) to create Universal Angular App.

- Create a new Angular App using `ng new ang-universal`.

[image]

- Open the app in `VSCode`.
- Add the Universal packages in the app by using
  `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine`.

[image]

- Run `ng build` to make the app ready for production.
- `dist` folder will be added in the application root directory.

[image]

***Deploy the App to Azure:***

- Create a new Azure App Service in Portal with `Node` runtime.

[image]

- In VSCode, Sign into Azure![enter image description here]
  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr6rZ.png) Account.
- Search for the app which we created in portal.

[image]

[image]

- Browse and select the `dist` folder.
- Continue to deploy the app.

[image]

Initially even I got the same error.

[image]

- Make sure your default document is added and delete the other documents.

[image]

- In Path mappings, add the name of the folder where the index.html resides and Save.
- We can copy the exact app name from `package.json` file.

[image]

- We can check the deployed files in KUDU Console.
  Path to KUDU - `https://YourAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`

[image]

[image]

[image]

> Web.config,I try to add it but after build it disapeare.

To avoid this issue, the `web.config` has to be added in the build output under assets in`angular.json` file.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that it will be SSR?

Comment: @Harshitha `npm run build:ssr`?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things are required to resolve this error.

Step: 1 - Inside your release application deployment, you need to add this "-Handler iisnode -NodeStartFile server/main.js -appType node" as per the below screen shot.

[Azure devop CD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg0XW.png)

Step 2: Create a new release and deploy it again & it should be as per below screen shot.

[App service folder strucutre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1epCF.png)

Step 3: Your web.config file should be similar to below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
    <rule name="StaticContent">
      <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
    </rule>

    <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
    <rule name="DynamicContent">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="server/main.js"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>

<!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <hiddenSegments>
      <remove segment="bin"/>
    </hiddenSegments>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>

<!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

</system.webServer>

Comment: I think your code of web.config has not right format