# Angular Universal Passenger error on Plesk server

Tags: angular, passenger, plesk, angular-universal

I have an Angular application running with Angular Universal on a Plesk server with Debian. The problem I have is that "some" pages are throwing an error and I can't find what's the problem.

For instance, I have a product page and depending on the id given in the URL, it loads a product or another. And some work and some don't.

Is a Debian (11.7) server managed with Plesk (18.0.54 update 1). Angular Universal is ran with Node 18.17.0.

Angular minifies everything to be put on production, but I have managed to de-minify it and I have gotten this:

```
/var/www/vhosts/.../dist/server/main.js:17345
: stack.top instanceof impl.HTMLTemplateElement
            ^

TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
at insertElement (/var/www/vhosts/.../dist/server/main.js:17345:29)
at insertHTMLElement (/var/www/vhosts/.../dist/server/main.js:17332:23)
at before_head_mode (/var/www/vhosts/.../dist/server/main.js:19836:31)
at HTMLParser.htmlparser.insertToken (/var/www/vhosts/.../dist/server/main.js:17296:17)
at emitSimpleTag (/var/www/vhosts/.../dist/server/main.js:17519:27)
at data_state (/var/www/vhosts/.../dist/server/main.js:17522:21)
at scanChars (/var/www/vhosts/.../dist/server/main.js:17120:23)
at Object.parse (/var/www/vhosts/.../dist/server/main.js:17029:37)
at exports2.createDocument (/var/www/vhosts/.../dist/server/main.js:29819:29)
at exports2.createWindow (/var/www/vhosts/.../dist/server/main.js:29846:38)

Node.js v18.17.0
```

The application itself is an Angular 16.1.6 application run with Angular Universal 16.1.1

Any thoughts or hints? I have searched a lot and found nothing...

Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56903846/angular-universal-with-domino-getting-right-hand-side-of-instanceof-is-not-a) help you out?

Comment: I saw that before posting my question but it is an Angular application so I can’t (or don’t know how to) configure that particular setting. I will look into that, but I suppose that making an production build using Angular CLI will use that.

Comment: I would be curious about how you configured your plesk website (document root, startup script, ...). I tried deploying an angular universal app to plesk, and it didn't work. the hosting company suggested to host it through asp.net core instead...

Comment: Sure! Node version: 18.17.0 Package administrator: npm Document root: /httpdocs/web/dist/browser Application mode: production Application url: home url of my app Application root: /httpdocs/web Application startup file: dist/server/main.js Customized environment variables: none. I have Plesk in spanish, so forgive me if any of the translations is not acurate :P