# Angular SSR deployment with ngx-translate implemented

Tags: angular, deployment, server-side-rendering, angular-ssr

I'm facing an issue with uploading my angular SSR project to Plesk server.

Initially, the project was a single language application, but now the requirement is to make it bilingual. So, I implemented ngx-translate.

Initially, there was a single main.js file, so it worked perfectly, but now we have two main.js files. One for the English locale and second for the Arabic locale.

So the crux of the matter is that how do I deploy the project on Plesk server.

server.ts

```
import 'zone.js/node';

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';
import 'localstorage-polyfill'
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';


// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(lang: string): express.Express {
  global['localStorage'] = localStorage;

  const server = express();

  let distFolder: string;
  const path1 = join(process.cwd(), `Mughrabi/browser/${lang}`);         // Running from the deployed version (production)
  const path2 = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/Mughrabi/browser');    // Running from the source (local development)


  if (existsSync(path1)) {
    distFolder = path1;
  } else {
    distFolder = path2;
  } 

  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/main/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
    extraProviders: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: lang }],
  } as any));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4200;
  const appEn = app('en');
  const appAr = app('ar');
  const server = express();
  server.use('/ar', appAr);
  server.use('/en', appEn);
  server.use('', appEn);
  // Start up the Node server
  
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';

run();
// if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
//   run();
// }

export * from './src/main.server';
```

Comment: So is angular universal on Plesk working for you at the moment? If not [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76805708/angular-universal-passenger-error-on-plesk-server?noredirect=1#comment135445176_76805708) someone posted his configuration. If you only have trouble with ngx-translate, I don't think you need to provide `LOCALE_ID`, that's purely for `@angular/localize`.

Comment: I have simply done it using an [`AppBrowserModule`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.browser.module.ts) and [`AppServerModule`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.server.module.ts). This should be okay

Comment: hi peter, thanks for your reply. No it's not working at the moment. I cannot figure out what to do in case of two locales because before that i used to give the path to node  as dist/browser/ and then it would load the html as it was already there but now we have two more folders from the production which are ar and en and then there is the html for the respective folders

Comment: @Pieterjan can you give a clue about AppBrowserModule and AppServerModule ?

Comment: You should just implement it the same way as in the project I linked. Don't forget to update your [`main.ts`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/main.ts#L47C53-L47C69)

Comment: I don't quite get it. Can you be a bit more specific? @Pieterjan

Comment: [Here's a guide](https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/angular-universal-ngx-translate-3cc18e951533)